# How do I use an input to call a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can I make a print to change to the input value?

```
import cryptowatch as cw
time = input("Time:") #15m, 1h , 1d
x = cw.markets.get("KRAKEN:ATOMEUR", ohlc = True, periods = [time])
print(x.of_15m[1][4]))
```

for example:

```
time = input("Time:") #1h
print(x.of_1h[1][4])
```

or:

```
time = input("Time:") #1d
print(x.of_1d[1][4])
```

EDIT:
I leave more information

`cryptowatch-sdk`

https://github.com/cryptowatch/cw-sdk-python

Module file where the functions are:(line 255)

https://github.com/cryptowatch/cw-sdk-python/blob/master/cryptowatch/resources/markets.py

Comment: What is the full range of possibilities for the input?

Comment: 1m, 3m, 5m, 15m, 30m, 1h, 2h, 4h, 6h, 12h, 1d, 3d, 1w. but with 15m, 30m, 1d it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't really test this properly since I don't have `cryptowatch` installed, but I think it would work. It uses the user's input to determine the name of an  `x` object attribute, and then uses `getattr()` to retrieve its current value.

```
import cryptowatch as cw

time = input("Time:")
x = cw.markets.get("KRAKEN:ATOMEUR", ohlc=True, periods=[time])

interval = getattr(x, 'of_'+time, None)
if interval is not None:
    print(interval[1][4])
else:
    print('Error: unknown time', time)
```